# How realistic would it be for the son of the emperor to go to college undercover?

Tags: medieval, education

How realistic would it be for the son of an emperor to go to some college town (think something like Oxenfurth from *The Witcher*) with a false identity? He pretends that he is some kind of lower-rank aristocrat in order to not get special treatment, and also for safety reasons.

I think it would be more likely that the son of the emperor has private tutors. Although he is not the heir, he is like the seventh child so it could be plausible. Let's say in order to prepare him to be some kind of educational minister, it would be best to go through the educational system.

Comment: This seems like a question about events that transpire in your world rather than some specific question about building your world. Also keep in mind that "Realistic" is a subjective quality that leads to answers that are subjective and opinion based rather than anything objective. Such questions aren't permitted on this site. We also don't permit soliciting ideas either.

Comment: The stated reason he does this is "to not get special treatment." This is common in stuff like Disney movies, but in reality it's aberrant in the extreme: folks _demand_ special treatment, and their rich & powerful parents probably moved heaven and Earth to guarantee they'd receive it (e.g. www.shorturl.at/ahIMS). That makes this a question about character motivation: "how likely is it that a royal child would desire an educational experience bereft of the privileges of rank," which is not worldbuilding. On-topic Q might be "how likely is it that he'd be identified?"

Comment: Like https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Jong-un ?

Comment: @Tom yes but special treatment is not necessarily better treatment, and there is a question of security issue also.

Comment: "Security by obscurity" is almost universally regarded as one of the worst strategies. The question of physical safety will be answered with trustworthy tools from the very large toolbox of conventional security measures: bodyguards, teaching at high-security sites, etc. The US Secret Service didn't put the Obama girls in trenchcoats and fake mustaches to smuggle them into a school for normies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Depends on the exact time, and society.

You tagged this [medieval](/questions/tagged/medieval). For most of the medieval time, colleges and universities where not quite what we think of today, and neither was society. In a way, a change in the mode of learning is *one* of the things which sets the medieval world apart from the modern.

There would certainly be tutors for the first years, but **university** could start at age 15 or 16, what we would today call college or even high school age. Teaching a "spare prince" the [seven liberal arts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_arts_education#History) might well have been a plan to set him up for an administrative (or religious?) position, reinforcing the rule of an older sibling as a trustworthy advisor.

**No newspapers and no photographs**

The [medieval](/questions/tagged/medieval) period had no printed books or newspapers. The printing press [made a great difference](https://This%20is%20not%20my%20trueborn%20heir.) in this regard.  The art styles also made it harder to recognize individuals. So a junior prince who did clain a different name would have had a good chance not to be recognized.

I agree with [David R](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/233938/how-real-is-that-the-son-of-the-emperor-goes-on-the-college-undercover/233942#233942) about the problems of disguising class, but this could be handled by claiming to the the [illegitimate offspring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legitimacy_(family_law)#Law) of some other, senior noble. With the support of that noble, the story might stick. *"Please take this young man into your university. He is not my legitimate heir. Here is the tuition. Please find some room for his servants, who wear my livery."*

**But this could backfire.**

The lack of *paparazzi* and photographs could become a problem later on, when it becomes time for the prince to act as a prince. You called it a 7th son, but mortality was high. The prince might well get a fairly senior place in the line of succession, and get called to act as a regent for the minor children of a dead brother, say. In that case, credible witnesses who swear that they went to college with him could be a problem. Some of the old pals might have gone on to study theology, become senior clerics ...

**The Russian Precedent**

[Peter the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Embassy_of_Peter_the_Great) traveled incognito through western Europe as the junior member of a delegation ostensibly led by someone else. But that incognito did not hold.

Comment: Peter was over two meters tall and well-known (at least among the people aware of such things) as one of the tallest men in Europe. Not one of the tallest leaders, one of the tallest full stop. His ability to blend in and be unnoticed would have been roughly as successful as Shaquille O'Neill trying to go incognito at a business conference.

Answer (score 8):

Human children go through stages in their development. Early on, they are bonded to their parents. But teen years are where they break free from parents and bond with a tribe. In royalty, that is a very difficult challenge (see the difficulties that the British royalty had with Prince Harry).

While a royal family might send their son to a university for that process, the traditional method is to send him to a baron to foster - to be a squire in that household. Why? Because someone who has grown up with privilege has quite a number of unthinking habits that other people just don't have and who recoil from someone who has them. Putting him with a baron will keep him among those with privilege and those habits won't cause social problems. Also, in this way, the son will have formed friendships with those with whom he will go into battle.

While an idealistic son might want to try to go "undercover", the unconscious thought processes are so different as to make him stand out. As a modern example, read "Black like me" where a white journalist attempted to go "undercover" as a black man in the deep south and had to be educated about how differently he had to think and behave. His unconscious patterns of behavior as a white man would have gotten him killed as a black man in the deep south back then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I remember correctly (or if we can trust the depiction in the Crown show) Prince Harry would be better off if he was incognito?

Answer (score 5):

**College undercover, with security also undercover.**

Your 7th son (of a 7th son!) goes incognito to school for the reasons you lay out.  He plays the role of a real person whom he somewhat resembles; an actual lower rank aristocrat his age.  The real boy is offered a position as a junior officer stationed abroad by the Emperor.  The real boy is dissolute and somewhat of a layabout but neither he nor his family are fools.

The risk though is that the Emperors son is found out by persons who wish to hold him for ransom.  With him in school are very capable persons charged with attending school and watching the Emperor's son.

The Emperors son does not know about these guardians.  One of them is actually a bully towards him; deep cover.  The son finds out in the course of the story.  The bully guardian thinks that besides him there is another one at the school but does not know who it is.  As it turns out she works for the school and is not a student.

---

/I think it would be more likely that the son of the emperor has private tutors/

You are right.  And it is more likely that the firstborn grows up to be Emperor.  The fact that the Emperor is himself a seventh son means his own track has been unconventional.  As is the Emperor himself.

Comment: The Emperor's son later falls in love with the "bully" and this becomes a major theme in books 2 and 3.

Comment: @Daron - your young adult fiction instincts are flexing.

Comment: The balance of power in their relationship mirrors the balance of power between the ruler and their citizens. The relationship and kingdom have in common that they only exist by consent of both parties. Which of the two really has the power? When he is ready to become Emperor the prince has all his homework done in the School of Life.

Comment: Don't steal my idea I'll know.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that in Shakespeare's play *Hamlet* (c.1599-1601) Prince Hamlet of Denmark has travellrd to Germany for education.

> However, a case has been made[4] that at an early stage in Hamlet—with its apparent history of multiple revisions—Hamlet was presented as a sixteen-year-old. Several pieces of evidence support this view. Hamlet attends the University of Wittenberg, and members of the royalty and nobility (Elizabethan or medieval Danish) did not attend university at age 30. Additionally, a 30-year-old Prince Hamlet would clearly have been of ruling age. Given his great popularity (mentioned by Claudius), this would raise the question of why it was not he, rather than his uncle, who was elected to succeed to the throne upon the death of King Hamlet.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Hamlet][1]

So by Shakespeare's time some members of royalty and nobility did attend universisties.  And it ispossible that some members of royalty might have begun going to niversities some time before whatever date you choose for theend of the middle ages.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Hamlet

Comment: Arguably Shakespeare's time is "early modern" rather than medieval.

Answer (score 2):

In medievalish setting, normally members of a royal family would be illiterate or at most, know how to read and write, taught by tutors.  Book learning was the field of clerks, whom they would have at hand to take dictation and read letters,.

This increased through the era and into modern times,but it was taught by tutors.  Remember the current Prince of Wales is the first British royal to hold a degree.

Also an educational minister is a modern thing and not early modern.  If a member of a royal or noble family went to college in medieval times, the safe assumption was that he was meant for the Church.

Comment: World is more Byzantine like than medieval western European. There you have characters like https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Psellos who was something like education minister at one point ("Chief of the Philosophers")

Comment: Then you have the issue that universities as such were medieval western European than Byzantine

Comment: The literacy rate of medieval royalty increased drastically betwween about AD 500 and AD 1500  So your answer would be true in some times ndd places, partially true in others, and false in still others.  Emperor Frederick II (1194-1250), for example, wrote a book about Falconry.

Comment: Actually, writing a book is not proof of literacy.  That's what you had clerks for.  It could be that he was -- that's the "at most."

Answer (score 2):

**The Emperor's son is a Bastard**

> Although he is not the heir, he is like the seventh child. . .

If you want to explain why he doesn't have private tutors, you are best making him an illegitimate child. This is a classic trope. He is a distant heir to the Golden Elephant Throne but no one knows. Maybe he doesn't know himself.

His mother is not the empress. He has his mother's last name. Illegitimate children are frowned upon. The emperor wants to "get rid of" the son by packing him away to a boarding school. The mother is happy since she could not afford this school anyway.

The relationship between the Emperor and the son can be whatever you want. He is the Emperor after all.

Comment: In a medievalish setting, the chances of a bastard inheriting in a time when they have university are extremely slim.  It was known in the earlier part, but by the time university arose, the laws of inheritance were locked down harder.

Comment: @Mary It is also hard for the seventh son to inherit. So we need a major event in either case. Of course the OP does not say they want the son to become Emperor. That was my idea.

Comment: Actually it was fairly easy for a legitimate seventh son to inherit, given the mortality rate at the time, but a bastard would mean a cousin.